# How to use Anaconda3 Terminal in VScode

Tags: visual-studio-code, anaconda3

I installed the Anaconda3 Packadge on my Windows11 and would like to use it within my VScode envernment but cant find it in the Terminal context

Terminal Context Screen

[image: 1]

Searched on goole for help and after 2h didnt find any solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Try to search for `Anaconda Prompt` in the windows search menu; it might be just an issue of conda not being added to the `path` variable. [Check here how to do so](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-setup-anaconda-path-to-environment-variable/).

Try to use [conda init](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/commands/init.html) inside the Anaconda Prompt (`conda init --all` for all terminals), or add it to Path and then initialize it in any of the other terminals.